AttributeError: 'LangchainLLMWrapper' object has no attribute 'agenerate_prompt' - trying to user HuggingFace LLMs with RAGAS to generate testset
I'm trying to use HuggingFace LLMs for RAGAS test set generation.
Ragas version: 0.1.10
Python version: 3.9.18
Here is my code:
import torch
from ragas.llms import LangchainLLMWrapper
from ragas.testset.generator import TestsetGenerator
from langchain_huggingface import HuggingFacePipeline
from ragas.embeddings import LangchainEmbeddingsWrapper
from langchain_community.document_loaders import PubMedLoader
from langchain_community.embeddings import HuggingFaceBgeEmbeddings
from ragas.testset.evolutions import simple, reasoning, multi_context
from transformers import AutoModelForCausalLM, AutoTokenizer, BitsAndBytesConfig, pipeline
from langchain_huggingface import HuggingFacePipeline


langchain_embeddings = HuggingFaceBgeEmbeddings(model_name="BAAI/bge-large-en-v1.5",
                                                model_kwargs={'device': 'cuda'},
                                                encode_kwargs={'normalize_embeddings': True})


bnb_config = BitsAndBytesConfig(load_in_4bit=True, 
                                bnb_4bit_use_double_quant=True, 
                                bnb_4bit_quant_type="nf4", 
                                bnb_4bit_compute_dtype=torch.bfloat16) # bits and bytes for model quantization

model_config = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("microsoft/Orca-2-13b", token="...")

langchain_llm = HuggingFacePipeline.from_model_id(model_id="microsoft/Orca-2-13b",
                                                  task="text-generation",
                                                  model_kwargs={"quantization_config": bnb_config,
                                                                "device_map": "auto"})

langchain_llm = LangchainLLMWrapper(langchain_llm)
langchain_embeddings = LangchainEmbeddingsWrapper(langchain_embeddings)

loader = PubMedLoader("liver", load_max_docs=10)
documents = loader.load()

generator = TestsetGenerator.from_langchain(
    generator_llm=langchain_llm,
    critic_llm=langchain_llm,
    embeddings=langchain_embeddings,
) 

distributions = {
    simple: 0.5,
    multi_context: 0.4,
    reasoning: 0.1
}

print("checkpoint")
testset = generator.generate_with_langchain_docs(documents, 1, distributions) 
print("checkpoint_2")
test_df = testset.to_pandas()
test_df.to_csv('test/testset_test.csv')

But I'm having this error:
AttributeError: 'LangchainLLMWrapper' object has no attribute 'agenerate_prompt'

